# how to set color with leaflet glify

Tags: colors, leaflet

I'm using the glify plugin for Leaflet, and can't for the life of me figure out how to set the color of my points to a function.

This works fine:

```
L.glify.points({
  data: data,
  map: map,
  opacity: 1,
  size: 10,
  color: 'red',
```

However this returns all black points:

```
L.glify.points({
  data: data,
  map: map,
  opacity: 1,
  size: 10,
  color: function(){
    if ( 1 > 0 ){ return 'red';}else{return 'blue';}
  },
```

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, needs to be formatted like this:

```
color: function(){
    if (1 > 0){
      return {
          r: 0,
          g: .51,
          b: .1
        };
    }else{
      return {
          r: 30,
          g: 1,
          b: 2
        };
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your hex color code into rgb form using below function

```
function fromHex(hex) {
    if (hex.length < 6) return null;
    hex = hex.toLowerCase();

    if (hex[0] === '#') {
        hex = hex.substring(1, hex.length);
    }

    var r = parseInt(hex[0] + hex[1], 16),
    g = parseInt(hex[2] + hex[3], 16),
    b = parseInt(hex[4] + hex[5], 16);
    return {
        r: r / 255,
        g: g / 255,
        b: b / 255
    };
}
```

and then return it like this :

```
L.glify.points({
  data: data,
  map: map,
  opacity: 1,
  size: 10,
  color: function(){
    if ( 1 > 0 ){ 
        return fromHex("#FF0000");
    }else{
        return fromHex("#0000FF");
    }
  }
});
```